# Kotlin Lambda with generic input parameter gets inferred to Nothing when stored in a collection

Tags: kotlin, generics, lambda

I have the following classes

```
class EventHandler<A : Aggregate, E : Event<A>>(
    val eventClazz: KClass<out Event<A>>,
    val handle: suspend (E) -> Unit
)

class Projection(vararg handlers: EventHandler<out Aggregate, out Event<out Aggregate>>) {
    val handlers = handlers.asList()
}
```

Now I want to invoke the handlers `handle` function. The `Handler` is stored in a `Projection`s `handlers` list.

```
val subscriptionFilterBuilder = SubscriptionFilterBuilder()

projections.forEach { projection ->
    projection.handlers.forEach { handler: EventHandler<out Aggregate, out Event<out Aggregate>> ->

        val eventType = getEventType(handler.eventClazz)

        val filter = subscriptionFilterBuilder.withEventTypePrefix(eventType).build()

        val options = SubscribeToAllOptions.get().filter(filter)

        val handlerTarget: KClass<out Event<out Aggregate>> = handler.eventClazz

        coroutineScope.launch {
            eskWrapper.subscribeToAll(
                options = options,
            ) { subscription, event ->
                val deserialized: Event<out Aggregate> =
                    serDes.deserialize2(event.originalEvent).eventPayload

                coroutineScope.launch {
                    handler.handle(deserialized)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler gives me the error `Type mismatch: inferred type is Event<out Aggregate> but Nothing was expected` for the line `handler.handle(deserialized)`.

I guess this is because of the way I store the handlers in the Projection but I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to ensure type safety in my case.

I can add a function to the `EventHandler` which takes care of deserialization and invoking the actual handling function. Since this `handleWithSer` function (don't use this name) is aware of the generic types this approach works.

```
class EventHandler<A : Aggregate, E : Event<A>>(
    val eventClazz: KClass<out Event<A>>,
    val handle: suspend (E) -> Unit,
) {
    val handleWithSer: suspend (RecordedEvent, EventPayloadSerDes) -> Unit =
        { event: RecordedEvent, serder: EventPayloadSerDes ->
            val event = serder.deserialize<A, E>(event)

            handle(event.eventPayload)
        }
}
```

If there are other ways to get the correct type from the collection let me know.